# Receiving Data From Universal Robot and Decoding

Tags: python, python-3.x, decode, robot

I am working on a project where we are looking to get some data from a universal robot such as position and force data and then store that data in a text file for later reference. We can receive the data just fine, but turning it into readable coordinates is an issue. An example data string is below:

b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\xbf\x00\x00\x80\xbf\x00\x00\x80\xbf\x00\x00\x80\xbf\x00\x00\x80\xbf\x00\x00\x80\xbf\x00\x00\xc0?\x00\x00\x16C\x00\x00\xc0?\x00\x00\x16C\x00\x00\x00?\xcd\xcc\xcc>\x00\x00\x96C\x00\x00\xc8A\x1e\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x88\xfb\x7f?\xd0M><\xc0G\x9e:tNT?\r\x11\x07\xbc\xb9\xfd\x7f?~\xa0\xa1:\x03\x02+?\x16\xeb\x7f\xbf#\xce\xcc\xbc9\xdfl\xbbq\xc3\x8a>i\x19T<\xf3\xf9\x7f\xbf\xb4k\x87\xbb->\xc2>\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80?\xdb\x0f\xc9@\xa7\xdcU@\xa7\xdcU@\xa7\xdcU@\xa7\xdcU@\xa7\xdcU@\xa7\xdcU@\xfe\xff\xff\xff\xfe\xff\xff\xff\xfe\xff\xff\xff\xfe\xff\xff\xff\xfe\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xecb\xc7@\xecb\xc7@\xecb\xc7@\

*not entire string received

At first I thought it was hex so I tried the code:

```
packet_12 = packet_12.encode('hex')
x = str(packet_12)
x = struct.unpack('!d', packet_12.decode('hex'))[0]
all_data.write("X=", x * 1000)
```

But to no avail. I tried several different decoding methods using codecs and .encode, but none worked. I found on a different post here the two code blocks below:

```
y = codecs.decode(packet_12, 'utf-8', errors='ignore')


packet_12 = s.recv(8)
z = str(packet_12)
x = ''.join('%02x' % ord(c) for c in packet_12)
```

Neither worked for my application. Finally I tried saving the entire sting in a .txt file and opening it with python and decoding it with the code below, but again nothing seemed to happen.

```
with io.open('C:\\Users\\myuser\\Desktop\\decode.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    text = f.read()

with io.open('C:\\Users\\myuser\\Desktop\\decode', 'w', encoding='utf8') as f:
    f.write(text)
```

I am aware I might be missing something incredibly simple such as using the wrong decoding type or I might even have jibberish as the robot output, but any help is appreciated.

Comment: It looks like binary data, so the struct module is probably the way to go.  But you need to know the format of the data being sent to unpack it properly; ideally this information should be found in the product's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to receive data from the robot with python is to use Universal Robots' [Real-Time-Data-Exchange Interface](https://www.universal-robots.com/articles/ur/real-time-data-exchange-rtde-guide/). They offer some python examples for receiving and sending data.
Check out my GitHub repo for an example code which is based on the official code from UR:
https://github.com/jonenfabian/Read_Data_From_Universal_Robots

Comment: Hi Fabian, your advice is probably very wise but it is not so specific to the question asked. I suppose it would be preferable to explain how to use the interface and package you mentioned to solve the specific problem